# Error when testing a keras model defined using Sequential()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Firstly, i am a noob at this. This is my first time with CNN model. I defined the model using
`from keras.models import Sequential`

i did not make any customisation in it. this is the code : https://github.com/kumarvivek9088/aslsigndataset/tree/main

when i run this code, i get the error: TypeError: Could not locate class 'Sequential'. Make sure custom classes are decorated with `@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()`

I do not know what this means. Please help.

I tried to check if there was any error in the code but couldnt find any, since the model was saved succesfully, and i got the json and h5 extension files of the model.

i suspect that the Sequential is the root cause. I do not know why tho. ALso the training file is this: https://github.com/kumarvivek9088/SignLanguageDetectionUsingCNN/blob/main/trainmodel.ipynb

Comment: Please provide the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so others can better understand or reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

According to the second link you posted, I looked, it seems that the training process has stopped